# Using Capo to Unstring and Restring the same Strings (Acoustic Guitar)

Tags: acoustic-guitar, maintenance

Disclaimer: This is not a question. More of a Share-Knowledge / Technique-Discussion. Leave a Comment should this turn out to not belong in MusSE.

I had an idea today. Please validate if this is Plausible. I don't think this was discussed earlier here in MusSE,

(This can't be done as far as I know in Most of the Electric and Classical Guitars as the strings are put in a way that they can only be removed in the bridge's direction)

When taking off the Acoustic Guitar Strings to do something in the Bridge's side, for examples, Adjust Truss Rod whose Acorn Nut is at the Sound Hole's opening or Maybe Sanding the Saddle,

1. Tuning pegs can be loosened up without causing the strings coming from Peg Heads,
2. Capo at a convenient Fret, say Octave,
3. Take off the Pins. Do whatever the purpose of Unstringing was
4. Repin strings, take of Capo and Tune back.

The problem is, maybe it's not possible to loosen the strings enough to be able to pin them back and not come out of the pegheads at the same time.

Or maybe this is a common thing. I thought of this because I don't want throw away my fairly new strings.

Comment: Hmm, I remember seeing an instructional video on YT that did this a while back. As you've written it, your post isn't structured as a question, but if you are interested in sharing this technique, you can rephrase the main post as a question and then post your solution as an answer. E.g. "What's a good way to perform maintenance on the bridge area of a guitar without unstringing completely?" Answer: "Use a capo." See here for some guidance: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: Nylon strings on classical bridges can be removed from the bridge without removing them from the tuning posts if they have enough winding.  Many electric guitars can't, although string sets are usually cheap enough to not be worth the time trying to save them.

Comment: @AlphonsoBalvenie Well with Covid Shutdowns it's pretty hard to get strings no matter cheap or costly

Comment: @RishiNandha_M - Fortunately, most adjustments to electric guitar bridges can be done with strings on.

Comment: True, I'm talking about, and tagged, Acoustic Guitar here

Comment: Capo helps keep things orderly, but it isn't strictly necessary.

Comment: As long as you have a few windings on the pegs, you should be able to disconnect many electric guitar bridges, although for many bridges, including any tremolo system I can think of, it's more trouble than saving a set of strings is worth. Floyd Rose systems clamp at the bridge and don't use ball ends, so that is a bit like removing bridge pins.

Answer (score 1):

I actually did this and this works to a certain extent.

Since the Tension in the strings is lost, (Yes, tenstion travels beyond the Capo if it's counterintuitive to you.), The strings loosen up at the neck and depending on the way strings are wounded they may slightly unwind. This is Reversible and thus purpose of putting the Capo on is not compromised.

Answer (score 0):

It will probably work, but a rubber band or piece of string round the neck at 12th/14th fret will do just as well.

Comment: I usually loosen the strings, remove the bridge pins and coil the strings together in a loose round, hanging from the headstock.  If I'm going to be moving the guitar around or hanging it for later work I will masking tape the string coil to the body to keep it from coming undone.